# JDK path error in Android Studio while build project

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Don't you think that it not enough information you've provided? Show your gradle.build

Comment: Just set the java home path.. Its not related to JDK error sometimes..